# System in thermal equilibrium with reservoir

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, conventions, equilibrium, foundations

Let's say I was trying to build Statistical Mechanics from scratch. I had studied the microcanonical ensemble and made the following definitions:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{T},$$
$$\frac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E} = \beta = \frac{1}{kT}.$$

Next suppose I wanted to study a physical system $A_s$ in thermal contact with a large reservoir $A_r$ at temperature $T_r.$ To understand the physics of the system $A_s$ the canonical distribution is generally taken as the starting point. But if I were building Stat Mech from scratch I would take the following steps:

1. Determine $S_s=S_s(E_s, V_s, N_s).$ Assuming that $V_s$ and $N_s$ are constant, this is some function $S_s = S_s(E_s)$. (This, may, of course, in reality be infeasible. But set that aside for now).
2. Determine $\frac{\partial S_s}{\partial E_s}.$
3. Set $\frac{\partial S_s}{\partial E_s} = T_r$ and then determine $E^*$ which satisfies this equation. Declare $T_r$ and $E^*$ to be the "equilibrium state." This state is the most probable **macrostate** state (the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics))).
4. The next question would be what the likelihood of other macrostates appearing is. To that end, there would be a matrix of transition probabilities per time step $dt;$ $f(T_i \to T_j)$ or equivalently $g(E_i \to E_j).$ Presumably, the transition matrices would be such that $T_r$ and/or $E^*$ end up being the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).
5. For many physical systems we would presumaby end up with transition probabilites such that the temperature/energy over time would be very strongly centered at $T_r$ and $E^*$ with only tiny fluctuations around these values.

Now, I worry that my question might be closed for lacking focus, because I do not have a very specific question here, but I hope I can elicit a discussion.

Question: Why *isn't* this approach taken? When studying a system in a reservoir the approach taken is different and takes as a jumping off point the canonical distribution. The temperature of the system is not defined as the time fluctuating variable $\frac{\partial S_s}{\partial E_s}$. Instead, it is only some time averaged variable, but any given microstate still has some probability of appearing. This seems strange. For example, in the usual approach taken, if a system (by some extraordinarily unlikely chance) jumped to the lowest energy microstate it would still have the same "temperature." But I would want to call that the system jumping to $T_s =0.$ After all, it seems physically no different than starting with an extremely cold system $A_s$, then putting it into the reservoir $A_r$ and letting its temperature approach $T_r.$

Can anybody elucidate the motivation for treating it the way it is normally treated?

Answer (score 2):

A key starting point of thermodynamics is that you assume the system is in equilibrium. Given that it is in equilibrium, there is some probability distribution to find the system in any given microstate. The probability distribution will be the one that maximizes the entropy, given the constraints on the macroscopic variables that exist (in your case, fixed particle number and volume, but able to exchange energy with the environment).

For the equilibrium distribution, there may be some small probability to find the system in a rare state, like all the particles in one corner. However, over a long enough time, this state will only occur very rarely. It is much more probable to be in a state where the particles are well mixed, and their

There's a rigorous way to associate the probability distribution over different microstates, with the time evolution of the system (what fraction of the time does the system spend in each microstate), called [ergodic theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory). Loosely speaking, it says that the time that the system spends in a given state, is proportional to the probability that it is in that state.

Therefore, I would disagree with your analysis of the "all particles in one corner" situation. I would say you cannot look at one particular snapshot in time to say if the system is in equilibrium; you need to look at a long enough time interval that you can say the system is visiting the various microstates in the way you'd expect given the equilibrium thermal distribution.

Here's another way to look at things. If you are really interested in starting the system in a special state (all particles in one corner), then the system is not in equilibrium, so you would need to analyze the system with non equilibrium statistical mechanics. You would find the distribution of states for the system would tend to move toward its equilibrium distribution.

Comment: Thank you. I still do not see the difference between starting at the lowest energy microstate and saying “this is not in equilibrium (yet)” vs. saying “this is in equilibrium and happens to be in the particular state of the lowest possible energy.” Perhaps I am missing the definition of “distribution”

Comment: What I would want to call “equilibrium” would be the macrostate such that $\frac{\partial S_s}{\partial E_s} = 1/T_r$. Then I would say that the system has tiny fluctuations around this equilibrium

Comment: Equilibrium POV: The distribution of states is the Boltzmann distribution. In principle, you can't make one observation of a microstate and conclude whether you are or aren't in equilibrium. You need to make many observations of many microstates and see if the observed distribution of microstates matches the Boltzmann distribution. In practice it's a little more complicated because we don't actually observe microstates, we observe averages over the Boltzmann distribution (eg, average energy).

Comment: Non equilibrium POV: You start off with the distribution being peaked around the known microstate, which is all the particles in the corner (say). The distribution will evolve over time to become the equilibrium distribution.

Comment: In practice which POV you take depends a bit on what question you are asking. If you are measuring the average energy, then the system ending up in a weird microstate might cause a fluctuation in the energy, but that will get beaten down if you wait longer. If you want to see the time evolution from some particular known state, then the non equilibrium POV makes more sense. So, the time scale on which you're modeling the system and assumptions you make about the system matter, to an extent. (But that's always true in modeling physical situations).

Comment: Another way to say it is that the equilibrium description of the "all particles in a corner state" is that one particular realization of the system at a fixed time happened to be some very rare state, but the underlying probability distribution is not changing with time. The non-equilibrium description is that "the distribution started off peaked around the weird corner state, then the *distribution* evolved to the equilibrium one." If the system is actually in the corner state, which one is "right" depends a bit on your perspective.

Comment: Suppose we had a very cold sample and we put it into a hot bath. *Over a very long time* the fact that it started out cold would not matter - the long term distribution of states would be the Boltzmann distribution. Similarly, suppose the sample started out as the same temperature as the bath - but randomly fluctuated to the cold value. Over a long time the distribution would still be the Boltzmann distribution. So, according to this definition, we could say that the very cold sample we started with is in equilibrium. This seems strange.

Comment: @Jbag1212 OK so the fact you say that the sample is cold before you put it in the bath means that you know its temperature. That means you *could* have done an experiment with that sample over however long you want, and would find the distribution of microstates at a low temperature. Then you change the conditions by putting it contact with a heat bath, and the system is no longer in equilibrium. If you do experiments in this new system, you'll find the distribution is not consistent with the one you started with.

Comment: I claim that according to the definition of equilibrium being used here, once you put the very cold sample into the hot environment, it would instantly be "at equilibrium" and at the new hot temperature. This is because over a very long time frame the fact that it started out cold would not matter.

Comment: Additionally, the fact that I know it is cold does not mean I needed to assume I could have measured it over a long time frame. I assume that it was an isolated system, and I put the right amount of energy into it to get to a specific **macrosate** where $\partial{S}/\partial{E} = 1/T_c$

Comment: @Jbag1212 No. There's a timescale for an out of equilibrium system to reach equilibrium. If you do averages over a much longer timescale that that, then sure, the transient effects at the beginning of the average will wash out, but that doesn't mean the system was in equilibrium at the beginning. However, you are hitting on a real tension, that the notion of equilibrium can get fuzzy when you think about how to define it in practice, instead of in principle. There's a kind of analogous tension with dice... we say probability 1/6 for rolling 1 means if you roll one die many times, then in the

Comment: limit 1/6 of the rolls will be a 1. But a real dice will start to physically decay as you roll it over and over again, the corners will get rounder, and the counts may not actually be what they are "supposed" to be. So there is something "fictitious" about the notion of the equilibrium probability distribution. It's a kind of statement about measurements you *could* make, *in principle*, if you ignore effects outside the system, like that on a long enough time scale the heat death of the Universe will occur.

Comment: However, there is no "in principle" trouble here. If you say that you have a system at temperature $T$, it means that *in principle* you can measure the distribution of microstates and it will follow a Boltzmann distribution with temperature $T$. In your example, the cold system at temperature $T_c$ before you introduce it to the heat bath has this "in principle" property. When you introduce it to the heat bath, it is no longer in equilibrium, so there is no temperature. After it reaches a new equilibrium state, the distribution of microstates will follow the new Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: Another way to say this is that statistical mechanics assumes the existence of a well-defined probability distribution over microstates. *In practice*, there is no such thing -- that distribution assumes the "system" is isolated (so ignores things like the heat death of the Universe), and there's no real way to directly measure the distribution of microstates. It's an imperfect mathematical model. But *in principle* it works -- saying something has a temperature $T$ means the distribution doesn't change in time and (at least classically) is a Boltzmann distribution with temperature $T$.